# Make code read-only in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to figure out what most are trying to do in reverse:

I would like to know how NetBeans makes the Matisse-generated code read-only.

In the picture below, the code in grey is generated by the GUI-Builder and is thus not editable. I would like another portion of my code to be the same way. The purpose of this is to prevent careless editing of a certain module by making the code harder to change.

[image]

Any NetBeans experts out there know how to do it (if it can be done) ?

Comment: is it possible that Netbeans relies on the fold description?

Comment: The GUI editor adds `//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents` after opening `<editor-fold>` tag and a `//GEN-END:initComponents` after the closing `</editor-fold> tag (which is hidden in the NetBeans editor itself as far as I can tell). I never tried to add that manually, but maybe it works if you do that outside of the NetBeans editor.

Comment: http://netbeans.dzone.com/nb-guarded-sections